# search script php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a search box where users can search for products, However I am stuck on one problem.

I would like to use **single query to search multiple tables** and then show the results. The problem is after the search results show up, when the users clicks on one of the products he should **see the item detail.**

I am able to do this with **single table** just passing the `id` variable via url to the second page and echoing all the rows on the second page. How can I do this with multiple table? The columns don't match in number. can someone give me a hint on how to show the details for multiple tables? Just like ebay or amazon does.

```
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, WHERE TABLE1.title = ? OR TABLE2.title = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $title);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `select t1.*, t2.*, t3.* from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 where t1.title=? or t2.title=? or t3.title=?`

Comment: Why do you have the products in multiple tables? O.o

Comment: they are different products not just one, like Smartphones, clothes, furnitures

Comment: I would still place them in the same table. Surely many columns are the same (id, product_number, name, price, main_image, active, etc). Then I'd pull out category, images, stock, perhaps price, custom category fields, etc. This would enable you to place an item into multiple categories, have the same image(s) on multiple products, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t1.* ,t2.* FROM TABLE1 t1, TABLE2 t2 
                               WHERE t1.title = ? OR t2.title = ? ");
```

Comment: what t1, t2 stands for? id?

Comment: @echo_Me are you serious?

Comment: @user2708382 this is NOT the answer

Comment: @YourCommonSense this solution helped him and solved his problem , why are you making big ADVERTISEMENT here ?

Comment: it cannot help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

For best result I think you need to redesign those products table.
Try the following approach.
create one table for `product_categories` with at least two fields, `category_id,category_name`. then create another table for `product_lists`. with at least  three fields `product_id, category_id, product_name`.Note `category_id` is foreign key on `product_lists` table.
Then create another table for `product_details` with at least three fields `detail_id,product_id,details`.Note product_id is foreign key on `product_details`.

This is just example you can do more than this. Then you can join the above table using their foreign keys and primary key, you solve the problem of multiple tables ids. As you see on your following page the id will be useful on product_lists table.